# php imagettftext font position

Tags: php, text, position, imagettftext

I'm using `imagettftext()` to write a letter into an image. The problem is that I don't know what's the letter position inside the image.

[image]

As you can see, I drawn border of the image and of the letter using `imagettfbbox()`, but the letter border is on the left also when the letter is on the right.

So the question is: How can I know where the letter starts (on the x axis)? Every letter looks like having a different "offset" and I just want to know it to draw the black border.

This is the code I used to create the images of the link above:

```
//$w,$h,$bl(baseline) and $s taken from a text in an html page

$string = "a";
$font = "font/times.ttf";
$h = 247;
$w = 94; //106 for letter "b"
$bl = 54;

header('Content-type: image/png');
$im = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);

$back = imagecolorallocate($im, 200, 200, 200);
$asd =  imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 255, 255);

imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, $w, $h, $back);

$x = 0;
$y = $h-$bl;
$s = 212 * 0.75;

imagettftext($im,$s,0,$x,$y,$asd,$font,$string);

$prova = imagettfbbox($s, 0, 'font/times.ttf', $string);
imageline($im,$prova[0],$h - $bl + $prova[1],$prova[2],$h - $bl + $prova[3],imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0));
imageline($im,$prova[4],$h - $bl + $prova[5],$prova[2],$h - $bl + $prova[3],imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0));
imageline($im,$prova[4],$h - $bl + $prova[5],$prova[6],$h - $bl + $prova[7],imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0));
imageline($im,$prova[0],$h - $bl + $prova[1],$prova[6],$h - $bl + $prova[7],imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0));
imageline($im,$prova[0],$h - $bl + $prova[1],$prova[4],$h - $bl + $prova[5],imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0));
imageline($im,$prova[2],$h - $bl + $prova[3],$prova[6],$h - $bl + $prova[7],imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0));

imageline($im,0,0,$w,$h,imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 255, 0));
imageline($im,0,$h,$w,0,imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 255, 0));

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the reason the in the Manual page of the function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php#97357